# Where is the default CA certs used in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, openssl

I'm connecting to a server whos cert is signed by my own CA, the ca's cert had installed into system's keychain.

connecting with `openssl s_client -connect some.where` says `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

but i cant connect with nodejs's tls/https module, which fails with 
`Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN`

but connecting to a normal server (i.e google.com:443) works fine.

seems that nodejs's openssl is not sharing same keychain with system's openssl.

but I cannt find where is it. i tried overide with `SSL_CERT_DIR` but not seemed working.

BTW: i can bypass the server verifying by setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` , but that's not pretty enough ;)

Im using OSX 10.8.3 with OpenSSL 0.9.8r, node v0.9.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default root certificates are static and compiled into the node binary.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.2.0/src/node_root_certs.h

Answer (score 12):

You can make node use the system's OpenSSL certificates. This is done by starting node via:

```
node --use-openssl-ca
```

- See the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/cli.html#cli_use_bundled_ca_use_openssl_ca) for further information.
- See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate) on how system certificates are extended for Debian and Ubuntu

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: This worked. Definitely better than bypassing the SSL security.

Comment: You saved my Birthday! owe you a beer mate.

The server I inherited was running an old version of node v6.6.something so using the --use-openssl-ca flag would return a "BAD OPTION" message. This flag has been introduced in node v 6.11.0 so for those who are given a vintage setup like I got update to 6.11.0 it solved the TLS Handshake issue. I will now test how far in version I can go before the app that is hosted on the server dies

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the [tls module](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) (and it seems like you are) with `tls.connect` you can pass a `ca` param in the options that is an array of strings or buffers of certificates you want to trust.

Comment: yes,I know that, but in my case, the request is made by a npm module, i dont want to change its code...

Comment: OK finally i added a `https.globalAgent.options.ca = /*something*/` into the first line of main js file. not a perfect solution though.  Thank you anyway!